# Client certificate validation with custom store not working

Tags: .net, kubernetes, ssl, x509certificate, client-certificates

For one of our projects we require only one endpoint of a service to have client certificate validation. The code will be running on Kubernetes and I've passed the client certificate through to the pod in the form of a header. This seems to be received by the code without any problems.

Now, the client certificate needs to be in a specific chain of certificates (they're signed by the government and not trusted by default). My approach was setting a `CustomTrustStore` with the entire chain of certificates. This does not seem to give me the result I was looking for.

So I've added the following:

```
services.AddCertificateForwarding(options =>
{
    options.CertificateHeader = "ssl-client-cert";
    options.HeaderConverter = (headerValue) =>
    {
        X509Certificate2? clientCertificate = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue))
        {
            clientCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(WebUtility.UrlDecode(headerValue));
        }

        return clientCertificate!;
    };
});

services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCertificate(options =>
{
    options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
    options.ChainTrustValidationMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
    options.CustomTrustStore = getTrustStore(configData);
    options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
    {
        ...
    };
});
```

The forwarding seems to work, the breakpoint shows that `clientCertificate` has a correct value.

The `getTrustStore` method returns an `X509Certificate2Collection` with all the certificates (simply loads a bunch of .CER files, puts them in an `X509Certificate2` object and adds it to the collection):

- Root certificate (Government)

  - Intermediate (Government)

    - Intermediate (Reseller1)
    - Intermediate (Reseller2)
    - Intermediate (Reseller3)

The client certificate needs to be purchased from one of the resellers and be part of that chain.

Local debugging makes the certificate check succeed (ends up in the `OnCertificateValidated` event), even if the `X509Certificate2Collection` is missing some certificates. Is it looking at my computer's store anyway? Deployed inside Kubernetes it seems to fail (ends up in the `OnChallenge` event), no matter what. There's no additional logging either.

I tried debugging but I got stuck and have no idea where to look. The documentation on these methods is pretty minimalistic. All controller methods have the correct `Authorization` attribute with the correct scheme provided.

Answer (score 2):

For best results, the root certificate should be the only one in `CustomTrustStore`, the remainder should be in `ExtraStore`.  But, since no one understands that, we were nice and let the `CustomRootTrust` mode just copy everything that's not self-signed over into ExtraStore.  (A theoretical future mode of `CustomAnchors` would tell the chain engine to stop at the first certificate it finds in CustomTrustStore... not the first one that's self-signed).  Though I'm not sure how those X509ChainPolicy properties map to the ASP.NET versions, maybe you can't influence ExtraStore at that level.

> Local debugging makes the certificate check succeed (ends up in the OnCertificateValidated event), even if the X509Certificate2Collection is missing some certificates. Is it looking at my computer's store anyway?

Yes. The chain engine will use your computer's cache of certificates (in the CurrentUser\CA, CurrentUser\My, LocalMachine\CA, and maybe LocalMachine\My stores... and possibly in the CU/LM Root and/or ThirdPartyRoot stores) in addition to the ones you specified programmatically for *building* the chain (it will also, unless disabled, attempt to download anything it can't find via a mechanism called "AIA fetching").  Since you're in a custom trust mode it will only call the chain *trusted* (and thus, successful) if it contains the root certificate that you specified in your custom collection.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue originated from the communication between Kubernetes (NGINX) and the code. The certificate was added as an HTTP header but not correctly processed.

Adding the following code to the `Startup` fixed it:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
   options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
   options.ForwardedProtoHeaderName = "X-Forwarded-Proto";
});
```